# How to open a WPF Popup when RadioButton checked?

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a `RadioButton` and a `Popup`. I want to open `Popup` when checked `RadioButton` and close `Popup` when `LostFocus` of it, without unchecked `RadioButton`.

I use this code.

```
<StackPanel>
 <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonSave" IsChecked="{Binding IsSave}">Save</RadioButton>
 <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonNotSave" LostFocus="RadioButtonNotSave_OnLostFocus" IsChecked="{Binding IsSave,Converter={StaticResource ToNegativeConverter}}">Not Save</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
<Popup x:Name="Popup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=RadioButtonNotSave}" StaysOpen="True" Placement="Left" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=RadioButtonNotSave}"></Popup>

private void RadioButtonNotSave_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

It is open popup when checked but when lostfocuse unchecked radiobutton.

I set `Mode=OneWay` for `IsOpen` , it is open popup and don't unchecked radionButton in lost focuse, but it worked for one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it only in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RadioButtonAndPopup.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
            </Style>
      </StackPanel.Resource>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBtn" Content="TestPopup"/>
        <Popup x:Name="myPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioBtn, Mode=OneWay}" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False">
            <Border Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock>Popup</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Setting StaysOpen false, you will be able to close the Popup by clicking anywhere outside it.

**Update 1:**

Add this in the StackPanel.Resources and name your Popup.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
      <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
</Style>
```

And this will be added to codebehind:

```
private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     myPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

So now the Popup will be opened on that Click event and not from the IsChecked binding.

Comment: Thanks, but when i use `Mode=OneWay` it is work For a time runs. If i click on radiobutton don't open Popup

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
private void RadioButtonNotSave_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   IsChecked = false;
}
```